# Importing products via csv file in Android Market

Tags: android, csv, product

I am trying to import CSV file:

```
"45098","published","managed_by_android","false","ru_RU; Гениальность и помешательство; Вы собираетесь приобрести эту аудиокнигу. Приятного прослушивания!","false","RU; 1000000"
"45105","published","managed_by_android","false","ru_RU; Старое житье; Вы собираетесь приобрести эту аудиокнигу. Приятного прослушивания!","false","RU; 1100000"
"52608","published","managed_by_android","false","ru_RU; Этруски: тайные страницы европейской истории; Вы собираетесь приобрести эту аудиокнигу. Приятного прослушивания!","false","RU; 1200000"
"52911","published","managed_by_android","false","ru_RU; Иван Грозный; Вы собираетесь приобрести эту аудиокнигу. Приятного прослушивания!","false","RU; 1300000"
"52929","published","managed_by_android","false","ru_RU; Огненный бог Марранов; Вы собираетесь приобрести эту аудиокнигу. Приятного прослушивания!","false","RU; 1400000"
"892","published","managed_by_android","false","ru_RU; Гиперболоид инженера Гарина; Вы собираетесь приобрести эту аудиокнигу. Приятного прослушивания!","false","RU; 1500000"
"53261","unpublished","managed_by_android","false","ru_RU; Государственные реформы в России. Том 1; Вы собираетесь приобрести эту аудиокнигу. Приятного прослушивания!","false","RU; 1600000"
"53568","unpublished","managed_by_android","false","ru_RU; Истории московских улиц. Выпуск 1; Вы собираетесь приобрести эту аудиокнигу. Приятного прослушивания!","false","RU; 1700000"
```

But I see the error.
"Invalid price (country: [RU]; Product ID: [45 098])."

In what may be the reason?

Comment: Same error here, did you figured out?

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same error message. The problem seems to be that google limits the price range for in app purchase, although i don't know whats the range in rub, if u take eur the range goes from 50 euro cents to 100 euros. Your price of 1 RUB is around 0.02 euro cents, thus I think your problem is the same as mine.